# Hibernate mapping error - Unknown entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm a hibernate newbie and im receiving this error when trying to persist an object -

Error -->Unknown entity: org.apache.struts.register.model.Event

In my `hibernate.cfg.xml`, I define my mapping as,

`<mapping class="org.apache.struts.register.model.Event"/>`

My event class -

```
package org.apache.struts.register.model;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity;


import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table (name="event")

public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue ( strategy =  GenerationType.AUTO)
 private int eventId;
 private String eventName;
 private String eventDescription;

 public String getEventName() {
  return eventName;
 }

 public void setEventName(String eventName) {
  this.eventName = eventName;
 }

 public String getEventDescription() {
  return eventDescription;
 }

 public void setEventDescription(String eventDescription) {
  this.eventDescription = eventDescription;
 }

 public String toString(){
  return this.eventName + "," + this.eventDescription;
 }

}
```

EventDAO -

```
package dao;


import org.apache.struts.register.model.Event;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;


public class EventDAO {

    public static boolean registerEvent(Event u) {

         SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
         Transaction t = null;
         try  {
         Session s  = sf.openSession();
         t = s.beginTransaction(); // start a new transaction
         s.persist(u);
         t.commit();  // commit transaction 
         return true;
         }
         catch(Exception ex) {
             System.err.println("Error -->"  + ex.getMessage());
             if ( t!=null) t.rollback();  // rollback transaction on exception 
             return false;
         }
    }
}
```

`System.err.println("Error -->"  + ex.getMessage())`, is the line that throws the exception.

Thanks.

Comment: Its generally considered bad practice to put your code in someone else's package. So unless you actually work on the struts project then don't use `org.apache.struts.register.model`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity;
```

the hibernate `@Entity` is not enough to get your entity discovered. Use `javax.persistence.Entity` instead.

[See here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-entity):

> @javax.persistence.Entity is still mandatory, @org.hibernate.annotations.Entity is not a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that Hibernate doesn't know about `org.apache.struts.register.model.Event`; so either your config file has an error or Hibernate it not loading the file (maybe its in the wrong place or there are two files with the same name or something like that).

Enable logging at the level DEBUG to see which files Hibernate loads and which types it maps.

Also don't use `System.err.println("Error -->"  + ex.getMessage());`; this hides a lot of useful information. Use `ex.printStackTrace()` instead for debugging and `log.error("Can't register event "+u, ex)` if you plan to keep the output.